# Laravel 8: Getting 404 “Not Found” Page While Trying To Delete User

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm getting all users information at Blade, like this:

```
@foreach($users as $user)
    <tr class="gradeX">
        <td><a href="/admin/users/user/{{ $user->name }}">{{ $user->name }}</a></td>
        <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
        <td>{{ $user->role->name }}</td>
        <td class="actions">
        <a href="{{ route('users.edit', $user->id) }}" class="on-default edit-row" title="Edit User"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('users.destroy', $user->id) }}">
        @csrf
        @method('DELETE')
        <button class="on-default remove-row btn-svg" title="Delete User"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
         </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

As you can see, for deleting a custom user, I've added this:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('users.destroy', $user->id) }}">
        @csrf
        @method('DELETE')
        <button class="on-default remove-row btn-svg" title="Delete User"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
</form>
```

And at `destroy` method of the Controller:

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        $user = User::findOrFail($id);
        $photo = Photo::findOrFail($user->photo_id);
        unlink(public_path() . $user->photo->path);
        $photo->delete();
        $user->delete();

        return redirect('admin/users');
    }
```

But now, whenever I try to delete the user from blade, I get **404 Not Found** page. However the user still exists at the DB.

And when I add `dd($id);` at the Controller, I get this as result:

[image]

And user *14* exists at the table `users` just like below:

[image]

So what is going wrong here? How can I solve this issue and delete the user properly?

I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion from any of you guys...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: add type submit in button. and in route config file `web.php` give user route like this `Route::resource('users', 'UserController')`;

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 options left what can be wrong, either you can’t find the user. Or you can’t find the photo. Based on the provided information it think there is no photo. The method `findOrFail` will return a 404 when the model is not found, see also https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#not-found-exceptions.

So what you can do is add a `dd` before the photo check to see if the user is found. If that is true you can be sure it is the photo model. If that is the case, you should use `Photo::find($user->photo_id)`.

After that you can wrap your unlink in an if statement where you Check if the photo model is not empty

```php
public function destroy($id)
{
   $user = User::findOrFail($id);
   $photo = Photo::find($user->photo_id);
   if (!empty($photo)) {
     unlink(public_path() . $user->photo->path);
     $photo->delete();
   }
   $user->delete();

   return redirect('admin/users');
}
```